# Magento2 GET value "Under review by Fraud Service" in RESPMS parameter from test Paypal Payflow on payment time

Tags: paypal

GET RESPONSE FROM PAYPAL

> RESPMSG    Under+review+by+Fraud+Service
>   "transaction has been declined"

```
GET Param are from paypal
POSTFPSMSG  Review: More than one rule was triggered for Review
PREFPSMSG   Review: More than one rule was triggered for Review
PROCAVS A
PROCCVV2    P
RESPMSG Under+review+by+Fraud+Service
RESULT  126
SECURETOKEN 98uhf5vOncEq4uTf1LR8vBg3k
SECURETOKENID   a2c20746fd9eff2019cdd3238ea709cc
SHIPTOCITY  Crystal+Laos
SHIPTOCOUNTRY   US
SHIPTOSTATE IL
SHIPTOSTREET    52+West+Stt
SHIPTOZIP   61067
STATE   IL
```

Answer (score 0):

Login 
https://manager.paypal.com/

Click 
`Service Settings > Fraud Protection >Test Setup >Edit Standard Filters > Enable or disable your fraud filters, or modify their settings. Be sure to click Deploy button`